# How to share/pass parameter while calling raise in unix?

Tags: c, unix, signals, ipc

Assume I have in `main.c`:

```
void myfunc(int num)
{
    printf("%d \n", num);
    signal(SIGUSR1, myfunc);
}

int main(void)
{
    void (*prev_fn)(int);
    prev_fn = signal(SIGUSR1, myfunc);
    if (prev_fn == SIG_IGN) signal(SIGUSR1,SIG_IGN);
}
```

and in `.so` which `main.c` loads a `foo` function calls `raise`:

```
raise(SIGUSR1);
```

How can I pass an argument `char *` when calling to raise, apart from using an extern buffer?

Comment: You can't. `raise()` takes a single `int` argument, nothing else. Also, your signal handler must be defined as `void function(int)`, with no ability to add additional arguments either. Any additional information you want your handler to have must be in some sort of global variable.

Comment: You have described a stumbling block you faced when trying to implement a solution to a problem. Perhaps you can describe the problem you are trying to solve, and we can suggest a different way to solve it.

Comment: @twalberg I can't use globals since foo is in .so file and and can't access variables in the `main.c` I can use `extern` but I don't want.

Comment: Calling `printf()` from signal handler is UB.

Comment: @VladLazarenko, why is it UB,  what about `send()` over UDP ?

Comment: @0x90: Because you are only allowed to call async safe functions from a signal handler.

Comment: @VladLazarenko I didn't see it in the man page.

Comment: @jxh I want to call from .so to function declared and implement in a .c file dlopen it on runtime.

Comment: @0x90: The solution I posted still works, but the `main()` program has to load the `get_foo_buffer()` function from the `.so` file and put it into a function pointer that the signal handler can call when it needs it.

Comment: @jxh the problem is I can't use signals since in the handler I have to use io operation

Comment: @0x90: Your whole question is about a signal handler. I think you need to write a new question, making your requirements more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you wrote:

> I can't use globals since `foo` is in `.so` file and and can't access variables in the `main.c` I can use `extern` but I don't want.

What you can do is provide a function in your `.so` file that returns an appropriate buffer based on information available to the signal handler (the signal):

```
char * get_foo_buffer (int sig)
{
    char *buffer = 0;
    /* ... retrieve the right buffer ... */
    return buffer;
}
```

Now, the signal handler can call `get_foo_buffer(num)` to get the buffer from the shared library.